# Find the number of series

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

Find the number of series $(a_1,..., a_{2n})$ that have terms from ${\{0,...9\}}$ so that:

$$
11|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}a_i
$$

(this is not a homework)

There is a similar problem ([Problem 6](https://www.imo-official.org/year_info.aspx?year=1995)) in the IMO 1995.

Comment: Whatever it is, HW or not, one would expect you show some self effort, some work, some ideas on what's going on here...

Comment: $(0,....,0)$ or $a_{i}=0$ is a solution since $11|0$ is true.

Comment: Consider $1+z+...+z^9$ If we put $(1+z+...+z^9)^n$ the coefficient of $z^k$ in its expansion will be the number of ways to write $k$ as a sum of $n$ numbers from $\{0,...,9\}$. Similarly, in $f(z)=(1+z+...+z^9)^n(1+z^{-1}+...+z^{-9})^n$ the coefficient of $z^k$ is the number of ways to write $k$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}a_i$, with $a_i\in\{0,...,9\}$. Now we only need to remove from there the terms with exponents that are not multiples of $11$, consider $w=e^{2\pi i/11}$. Recall that $1+w+...+w^{10}=0$, and $w^{11}=1$. Then $(f(z)+f(wz)+...+f(w^{10})/11$ ...

Comment: has the terms of $f$ with exponents divisible by $11$. Finally, since we want to count all possible series for all possible sum divisible by $11$ we can take $(f(z)+f(wz)+f(w^2z)+...+f(w^{10}z))/11$ and evaluate it at $z=1$.

Comment: Now notice that we can simplify $f$. We have$f(z)=\left(\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}\right)^n\left(\frac{z^{0}-z^{10}}{z^{9}-z^{10}}\right)^n$

Comment: @ABC You have all the tools that you need.

Answer (score 3):

For a fixed $n$, let $ A_r $ be the number of sequences of $n$ terms, whose sum is $r \pmod{11}$. Then, we want the value of $ \sum A_r ^2 $.

As pointed out by ABC, the generating function $f(x) = \left ( 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^9 \right) ^n $ gives us the number of sequences of $n$ terms, with a total sum of $r$. We find the sum of those coefficients with the power mod 11, we use the typical counting trick. Let $\omega$ be a primitive 11th root of unity. We know that $ 1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \ldots + \omega^{10} = 0 $. For $ i \not \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$, we have $ f( \omega^i) = ( -\omega^{10i})^n$

We have $$ 11 A_r = \sum_{i=0}^{10} \omega^{-ri} f( \omega^i) = 10^n + \sum_{i=1}^{10} \omega^{-ri} (- \omega^{10i})^n = 10^n + (-1)^n \sum_{i=1}^{10} \omega^{(10n-r)i}. $$

In particular, this shows that for $r \neq 10n \pmod{11}$, we have $A_r = \frac{10^n-(-1)^{n}}{11}$. Otherwise, for $R \equiv 10n \equiv -n \pmod{11}$, we have $A_R = \frac{10^n+10 \times (-1)^n}{11}$.

Hence, we can now find the sum as

$$ \sum_{r=0}^{10} A_r^2 = 10 \left (\frac{10^n-(-1)^n}{11} \right)^2 +  \left( \frac{10^n+10\times (-1)^n}{11} \right)^2$$

---

Note: This solution is nice 9 because 2 less than 11, which makes $f(\omega^i)$ easy to evaluate. For a much more general case, the equations would not be pretty.

Comment: There is a wait of 14 hours until you get your bounty.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Could it be that you made a small mistake when replacing $(-\omega^{10i})^n$ by $-\omega^{10in}$ or is there something else you did? If so, there would be different answers depending on the parity of $n$, namely $10\left(\frac{10^n+1}{11}\right)^2+\left(\frac{10^n-10}{11}\right)^2$ for odd $n$ and $10\left(\frac{10^n-1}{11}\right)^2+\left(\frac{10^n+10}{11}\right)^2$ for even $n$, right? I suppose so, because the result you got for $A_r$ is not integer for even $n$, as $10^{2m}\equiv1\pmod{11}$. But apart from this, nice solution! It took me some time to understand but I learned much from it!

Comment: @barto Yes indeed! Updated. $A_r$ wouldn't have been an integer in certain cases.

Answer (score -1):

Since the second term is larger than the first term

-Sum = (2n * (2n+1))/2 - 2*(n*(n+1))/2
= n*(2n+1) -n*(n+1)
=n*n

(Sorry not used to site so plain english).

So 11 divides the series iff 11 divides n.

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)